# this.items is undefined mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

i'm new in MongoDB.

I'm try to do MapReduce in some BD. I define a map Function and a reduce function, but when i try to run mapReduce command it say "this.items is undefined".

Here is my code:

```
var mapFunction = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
        var key = this.items[i].Color;
        var obValue = {genero: this.items[i].Gender,
                       cinturon: this.items[i].Belts,
                       work_zone: this.items[i]["Work Zone"]};
        emit(key, obValue);
    }
 };

var reduceFunction = function (key, arValues){
    var nuCount = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arValues.length; i++){
        var obValue = arValues[i];
        if (obValue.genero == "F" && obValue.cinturon == "No" && obValue.work_zone == "No"){
            nuCount += 1;
        }
    }
    return nuCount;
};

db.trafic.mapReduce(mapFunction, reduceFunction, {out:"map_color_result"})
```

Comment: Please post your code directly in the question instead of a picture/screenshot.  It makes it much easier for someone to help you when they can copy/paste.

Comment: ok. Thanks, i will post it.